# custom tableviewcell and autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uitableview

so far I have used custom tableviewcell without IB and for one screen size and one orientation.

Now my app uses auto-layout and so it will support all kinds of device-orientation and all kinds of screen sizes(iPhone,iPad)

Now how can I design custom tableview cell with Auto-Layout in mind.

I usually hard-code the frame.

Now can I auto-layout my tableview cell too.

Is it possible that I can still use Tableview cell without using IB.

Help please

Comment: Yes it is possible. But why you want to design a cell without IB ? It will be very complicated to debug your table cell when you dont apply the constraints properly

Comment: @Mr.T I used to feel the same way, but once you have a couple of constraints factories and categories for adding constraints, it can actually be simpler to do it without a NIB, this of course depends on the complexity of the cell, but in my experience for very complex cells it ends up being easier to not use a nib at all.

Comment: I have to manually create constaints in code right by finding the size and orientation of device

Comment: @OscarGomez - Can you guide me how to do ?

Comment: @King See my answer, settings the constraints is really no different than it is in IB

Comment: see we can set auto-layout constraints in pure objective-c also huh ? we don't need IB right..Correct me If I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use any kind of UIView without using IB, this includes a UITableViewCell. What you could do is in your

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

method, you can configure all the constraints, you can set every single subview that you want for your tableview to CGRectZero, and add them to the cell's contentView, the cells contentView, will automatically have the proper size based on the tableview size and the insets. Therefore after adding all your subview to the content view like this inside your initWithStyle:

```
[self.contentView addSubview:mySubview]
```

you can call your own private method like configureConstraintsMyCustomTableViewCell, and configure all the constraints there.

Comment: So I have to apply my own logic for frame depending on the size & orientation of screen

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to care at all what the size and orientation is, and I mean at all, if you want for instance something to be wider in landscape vs portrait, simply don't sent a width constraint but set the leading and trailing constraint to the superview with some constant value that you want.

Comment: I am not able to understand clearly can you explain or point me to a sample..I am not able to undetstand

Comment: @King What part can I help you understand?

Comment: Can you give me a sample for configureConstraintsMyCustomTableViewCell ? it'd be helpful for me